# How can i change the UISearcherController row's height in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, search, swift2, uisearchcontroller

How to change searchController's rows height in swift? I have set up a tableview with searchController and i would like to make the rows height a bit higher . That would be great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
// swift 2.3
1. set tableView delegate

tableView.delegate = self

2. implementes the delegate method

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
}

// swift 3.0
1. set tableView delegate

tableView.delegate = self

2. implementes the delegate method

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                  heightForRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 200
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you write it in Swift 2.3 please ?